# Is there a way to log all bash displayed text (both input and output)?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, shell, history

As in title, I would like to log everything is displayed by the bash,
that is the inputs and the relative outputs.

Let's say I would like an "history" for everything, not only input commands.

I would like the log to be stored in different file, having for example one file per session (from the opening of a shell to its termination).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`script` utility is exactly what you need.